# pytorch initialize two sub-modules with same weights?

Tags: pytorch

I was wondering if there's a typical way to initialize two parts of one network to same some initial values? Say I got two separate auto-encoders for both query and document, and I would like to initialize the weights of these two auto-encoders to same weights (not sharing the weights).

Thanks!

Comment: I ended up with initializing the two auto-encoders using explicit random initializer with same random seed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the most easy way would be to init one of the sub-modules at random, save the `state_dict` and then `load_state_dict` from the other module.